# Overlay a watermark in avconv for a specific time

Tags: overlay, avconv

How to overlay the picture *label.gif* only from second 1 to second 10?
`*enable=between(t,1,10)*` didn't work

```
avconv -y -i input.mp4  -vf 'movie=label.gif [watermark]; 
[in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]' -c:v libx264 -crf 22 output.mp4
```

Comment: you don't have "enable=" anywhere in our commandline, could you post the command that you are actually running.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you will need to do is to generate the stream of video that consists of the single file. It is not enough to simply do `-i file.jpeg`, but you need to do `-loop 1 -i file.jpeg` (this will repeat the file indefinitely).

After that you can start applying different filters to that stream. The approach that i have done and tested on my computer is this:

```
avconv -i input.ogv -loop 1 -i logo.jpeg   -an \
  -filter_complex '[1:v]trim=start=1:end=2[ol]; [0:v][ol]overlay=eof_action=pass[final]' \
  -map '[final]' -c:v libtheora out3.ogv
```

Let's look at the command above and take it apart. As i have mentioned already `-loop 1` generates an unending stream. Then we take that stream [1:v] and pass it through the `trim` filter with `start` and `end` parameters. The beauty of that filter is that it doesn't touch the timestamps, so although we have cut that stream to be 1 second long, it will still only start at second 1. There are other parameters for the `trim` filter, but since you were using `between` from ffmpeg my `start` and `end` will be obvious to you.

Then we can simply take that stream and use that in the `overlay` filter, but we should specify `eof_action`, since we don't want encoding to stop when the loop stream has ended. The `pass` action means that we will just continue with the original stream as if nothing has happened.